# MemoryStream.ToBytes() memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, memorystream

i have an application with memory leak issues.
When investigating, i found that `Byte[]` keeps increasing, so i used Red-Gate ANTS Memory Profiler and i saw that theres one really big instance of byte[] (16,777,228 bytes). When i check the retention graph it shows this:

[image]

Now this is weird for me because i would expect to see a link between one of my classes to this memory stream.

What is lacking in my understanding? why does this memory increase happening and how do i stop it?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you ever close the stream?

Comment: I went over all MemoryStream instances and inserted using for each of them (before it was never closed..)

Comment: It can be considered that you are not disposing the streams. `using` pattern is a good choice while using streams

Comment: @EmrahSüngü Not sure what you meant here.. as i said, i added using for all the memorystreams so they should all be disposed

Comment: @TomerSomething but the leak is still happening?

Comment: Without code parts we can only speculate about the potential problem. With current details this question is not appropriate.

Comment: Its very hard to say, because to truly test it i have to do it in production environment.. besides the leak might not be caused by this memory stream so this is why i asked a very specific question.

Comment: Short answer is that `MemoryStream` cannot produce memory leak on it's own. You must've messed up something in different part of the code. Judging by the image you're keeping same instance of `MemoryStream` and just write bytes into it's internal buffer.

Comment: @m.rogalski i cant show code parts because i dont know where the problem is.. besides there are like 100 memory streams references in like 30 classes soooo...

Comment: There is too less information, we can't see how you're using the memorystreams. Is it static? field? local? constructor with byte[] as parameter. etc. Can you provide some more info?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I still have to pinpoint this instance location.. i dont know yet which class is handling it (which is 80% of the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Memory directly managed by .NET doesn't normally "leak". It is managed. `MemoryStream` is **very** like a `List<byte>` (more exactly it is a `Stream` implementation that internally uses a `byte[]`, handling it like a `List<byte>` would). It is so much simple that if you take a look at its code you can rewrite it in an hour. No black magic is done inside. No funny programming. Nothing.

So:

1. You are keeping references to the `MemoryStream` or to the `.ToArray()`.

or

2. You have pinned the result of a `.ToArray()` by using a `GCHandle`. Then the .NET won't free it.

Comment: Shouldnt i see in the retention graph that a class is holding this memory stream? this whats confusing to me.

Comment: @TomerSomething If you look at the graph, you have two `ToBytes()` methods. They aren't part of the `MemoryStream` (that has a `ToArray()`), so begin by taking a look at that method.

Answer (score 0):

You're either

- keeping the references to stream in your classes or
- there is a static field / property storing them. In both cases objects won't be released

In both cases objects won't be released and will be kept in memory

Comment: Shouldnt i see in the retention graph that a class is holding this memory stream? this whats confusing to me.

Comment: if it's a static property then it is not connected to *instance* of a class and you won't see it on retention graph (except for the property)